# Signing a Python built distribution-based exe

Tags: python, windows, installation, product

Let's say I have a simple package and I want to create a built distribution (in the form of an exe). My setup.py contains this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Testy',
      version='0.0.1',
      author = 'Joe S',
      author_email = 'joe@somewhere.com',
      packages=['testy',]
      )
```

And I turn the package into a built distribution via `python setup.py bdist_wininst`

This creates a exe, as expected, and it runs great. When I sign the exe, the file correctly gets a digital signature, but can't be run properly:

```
"Setup program invalid or damaged."
```

This error is discussed here, without a resolution: https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-distutils-sig/25567/

Does anyone know how I can create a Python built distribution with a SIGNED and working exe?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a similar question/answer that might help that uses `py2exe`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808946/295246

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @HEADLESS_0NE ! Sadly it looks like that zipfile parameter in setup.py only applies to py2exe. Still searching for something specific to built distributions (and would appreciate any help).